# How to export hair particles to Unity

Tags: particles, export, unity, hair

I made a chainmail in blender. Rings were made as a hair particles. I want to export result in Unity, but if I convert particles to mesh, chainmail file drastically increases its weight. 
Which workflow is correct for my case?

Now I have some ideas:

1. Somehow bake particles to mesh.
2. Export ring pattern and mesh separetely and simulate particles in Unity (dont know is it possible).
3. Make chainmail in a different way(still dont know how).

[image]

Comment: Probably you won't get very far as highpoly models as this in a game engine. You gotta consider to use a pbr material like this: https://www.textures.com/download/pbr0273/133949?q=chain

Comment: @FFeller, thx. I also figured out, that I should use materials.